# Send url to src other page

Tags: php

In the index page flowplayer if I change the value of the src = url with another, I view any video might be of interest to me, I wanted to make a page with a video playlist with several links where to click, send me to the index.html page of the player the new link and let me go then the player with the new source. I am new in programming, but with a great desire to learn, how can I pass several links to the value of src on the index.html page and simultaneously recall? I tried to send this way:

```
Send Page:

<html>   
<body>   
<a href="index.html?var="Http://mystreaming.com/video1.m3u8">Send Video 1</a>   
<a href="index.html?var="Http://mystreaming.com/video2.m3u8">Send Video 1</a>
</body>   
<html>
```

while the index page I have:

```
index page:
<?php   
$variabile_get = $_GET['var'];
?>

<head>
   <!-- Flowplayer library -->
   <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.2/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Flowplayer hlsjs engine -->
   <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/hlsjs/flowplayer.hlsjs.min.js"></script>
   <!-- player skin -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="skin/skin.css">

   <!-- site specific styling -->
   <style>
   body { font: 12px "Myriad Pro", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; text-align: center; }
   .flowplayer { width: 80%; }
   </style>

   <!-- for video tag based installs flowplayer depends on jQuery 1.7.2+ -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

   <!-- include flowplayer -->
   <script src="flowplayer.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-live="true" data-ratio="0.5625" class="flowplayer">

   <video data-title="Live stream">
   <source type="application/x-mpegurl"
        src=$_GET['var']>
   </video>

   </div>



</body>
```

I realize that if it does not work, or you mess up your submission method of varibile url or the method in which the index page should recognize the url that will start in the src =, can you help me and make me understand where and why not? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off your index page should have a `.php` extention if you want to use php code.

Secondly you're not using `$variabile_get` in your code

in your src you'll need to `echo` the variable you made at the top like so:

`src="<?php echo $variabile_get ?>"`

or

`src="<?= $variabile_get ?>"` for short

Comment: Thanks so much, so it works and above all I realized the mistake, one more thing, you can hide the address bar src = http: // xxxxx

Comment: Not that I know off. But i don't really see a reason why you would want that since you're already passing the src through the url. It might be possible but you would have have to look on SO for it. And if you can't find it ask another question